# Java : using objects created in a different class file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to recreate some board game on Android and I'm stuck with the use of objects.

I basically have one main activity class, which does all the UI changes and calculations, but I have to create the cards somewhere. I can do it with no problem in the main activity after creating a WonderCard class somewhere else.

Here's WonderCard.java :

```
package com.example.phil.test3;

public class WonderCard {

    int id;
    String name_full;
    String name_short;
    int view_path;

public WonderCard(int id, String name_short, String name_full, int view_path) {
    this.id=id;
    this.name_full=name_full;
    this.name_short=name_short;
    this.view_path=view_path;
}

}
```

And here's the object construction in the main activity :

```
card = new WonderCard[] {
                new WonderCard(0,"Olympia","La Statue de zeus à Olympie",R.mipmap.wondercard_0),
                new WonderCard(1,"Gizah","La Grande Pyramide de Gizeh",R.mipmap.wondercard_1),
                new WonderCard(2,"Rhodos","Le Colosse de Rhodes",R.mipmap.wondercard_2),
                new WonderCard(3,"Babylon","Les Jardins Suspendus de Babylone",R.mipmap.wondercard_3),
                new WonderCard(4,"Alexandria","Le Phare d'Alexandrie",R.mipmap.wondercard_4),
                new WonderCard(5,"Halikarnassos","Le Mausolée d'Halicarnasse",R.mipmap.wondercard_5),
                new WonderCard(6,"Ephesos","Le Temple d'Artémis à Ephèse",R.mipmap.wondercard_6),
        };
```

(sorry about the French)

So this all works, and from my main activity I only have to call, say,

```
card[0].name_long
```

to get an object's property.

Everything is fine for now, except I'll have to create more than 150 cards at some point. I want to keep my main activity as clean as possible and would like to get rid of the object construction 150 lines high in my main activity.

My question is : how can I create my cards and their properties on a **different file**, and call those created objects easily from my main activity file ?

(Android allows me to use an SQLite database, if it may help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest approach: put all the cards into database and just load them from there.

Not sure if I understood the question correct, but doesn't a plain old instance provider just provide the structure you need as follows?

```
public class WonderCardProvider {
    private static final WonderCard[] cards = new WonderCard[] {
        new WonderCard(0,"Olympia","La Statue de zeus à Olympie",R.mipmap.wondercard_0),
        ..
    };

    public static WonderCard[] getAllCards() {
        return cards;
    }
}
// Note that the `getAllCards()` should probably return in as unmodifiable (thus returning a collection instead of array).

card = WonderCardProvider.getAllCards();
```

Or is the question on having the definition of 150 cards outside any Java class? Then `.properties` files is the way to go.

Comment: It seems to have totally done the trick. I can get around with Java but I have much to learn when it comes to objects. I didn't think about using a third class (besides main activity and WonderCard). Your code was spot-on, and I learned something. You have my thanks.